# How to list members in a group using views Drupal 7?

Tags: views, organic-groups, users

I am using Profiles 2 and Organic groups.

I was successful in listing users via views > Users.

I am using "profiles 2" module to collect and store details of users rather than the core drupal user management.

I have created few groups using "organic groups" module.

My question is how to list all the "PROFILES" (created via profile2 module) of members belonging to a group using views ?

Comment: Please don't use the title to replicate tags.

Comment: can you please be more specific, am new to this stuff...thanks

Comment: You tagged the question with "profile2", which makes sense, but you also duplicated the tags in the title, by writing something like "[profile2]" there. I removed them, and simply wanted to make you aware why I did so. :)

Answer (score 2):

I had forgotten to add Groups Audience as a field in the Profile type created by Profile 2 which in my case was "Main Profile".

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used neither OG nor Profile2, but since no-one else has given you a more specific answer, I will provide a general one.

When you create a View, your first choice is, "What do list", it's possible that "Profile2" provides a "profile" specific choice here, but most likely, you should go with the regular "user" list.

Then, the filtering on a specific group, is done with a contextual filter, probably on group id.

I would recommend you learn to understand the basic structure for Views first, and you will be able to understand the answer to a whole class of questions similar to this one. Some video tutorials [can be found here](http://dev.nodeone.se/node/747).

Comment: well thank u for the answer but i found out, that in profile 2 fields i should have added groups audience...which solved the problem...